# Is there a free circuit simulator program that is able to make a SPICE (.cir extension) file?

Tags: simulation, spice

I don't have a lot of money and I need some program that can simulate circuits and output a .cir file.

Comment: What have you already done to find and locate tool(s) that may meet your needs? Just writing out a single sentence asking others to know what you need (without a working crystal ball) and to then write an answer that precisely meets those needs isn't likely to work well and it's probably not appropriate here, besides.

Comment: A SPICE file is the input to a simulator, not the output.

Comment: I need a simulator that outputs a SPICE file from a circuit that you draw, I think Micro-cap (recommended by another answer) does this but I'm testing it

Comment: A `.cir` file is just a netlist and SPICE, in geenral, is extension-agnostic. That means that if you have a `.net` file (or any other netlist with any other extension) you can easily change its extension and use it as it is. And what you're talking about is exporting a schematic to a netlist, and I think pretty much every SPICE simulator can do that, since it has to convert whatever schematic it has to a netlist (which is the SPICE code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Micro-cap is free and can accept and output .cir files.

More here: http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm

Answer (score 1):

Quite Universal Circuit Simulator QUCS accepts SPICE models.

http://qucs.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a simulator which - based on a circuit diagram - gives you a corresponding .cir file.
The name of the simulator is SAPWIN (can be downloaded from the University of Firenze webside). However, the used opamp and transistor descriptions (models) are rather simple.